# no output from trigger when expected

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm trying to get my trigger to fire when inserting/deleting/updating a student into the enrols relation if they enrolled before the year 1993. After which I want it to raise exceptions.

None of my exceptions are raising my DBMS output that I have given it.

Inserting seems to be working because paper_cost reduces by 10% when I inserted a new tuple (no exception is raised though)

Deleting and Updating don't seem to be doing what I expect them to do -- Deleting I expect it to increase the paper_cost by 10%.

Any ideas? I'm stuck in a brain-loop here!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER discount_160
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON enrols
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    excep EXCEPTION;
    updated EXCEPTION;
    deleted EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
 IF UPDATING THEN
  IF (:OLD.date_enrolled < TO_DATE('01-Jan-1993', 'dd-mon-yyyy')) THEN
     IF (:OLD.paper_code = 160) THEN
        UPDATE papers
        SET paper_cost = paper_cost* 0.9
        WHERE papers.paper_code = :OLD.paper_code;
        RAISE updated;
   END IF;
END IF;
ELSIF INSERTING THEN --inserting
  IF (:NEW.date_enrolled < TO_DATE('01-Jan-1993', 'dd-mon-yyyy')) THEN
     IF (:NEW.paper_code = 160) THEN
        UPDATE papers
        SET paper_cost =  paper_cost * 0.9
        WHERE papers.paper_code = :NEW.paper_code;
        RAISE excep;
     END IF;
  END IF;
ELSE --deleting
    IF (:OLD.date_enrolled < TO_DATE('01-Jan-1993', 'dd-mon-yyyy')) THEN
       IF (:OLD.paper_code = 160) THEN
          UPDATE papers
          SET paper_cost = paper_cost * 1.1
          WHERE papers.paper_code = :NEW.paper_code;
          RAISE deleted;
       END IF;
    END IF;
   END IF;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN excep THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('inserted and updated');
   WHEN updated THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('updated');
   WHEN deleted THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('deleted');
END;
/
```

My enrols table:

```
CREATE TABLE enrols
   (paper_code         INT     ,
   student_id         INT      REFERENCES student(student_id),
   date_enrolled      DATE,
   dept_id            INT,
   PRIMARY KEY(paper_code, student_id, dept_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (paper_code, dept_id) REFERENCES papers(paper_code, dept_id));

INSERT INTO enrols VALUES
   (160, 172384, TO_DATE('22-Mar-1994', 'dd-mon-yyyy'), 01);
```

Comment: Your trigger won't fire on DELETE as you have only defined it BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE - you need to add OR DELETE. Your test-insert will fire the trigger but nothing will happen, as the date is later than 1993.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "None of my exceptions are raising my DBMS output that I have given
>   it."

DBMS_OUTPUT displays to the screen.  In most clients it is disabled by default.  Switching it in on varies according to the client.  In SQL*Plus it works like this:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger t34_trg 
  2  before insert on t34 for each row
  3  begin
  4      dbms_output.put_line('T34 '||:new.col1);
  5  end;
  6  /

Trigger created.

SQL>             
SQL> insert into t34 values (42)
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> insert into t34 values (42)
  2  /
T34 42

1 row created.

SQL>
```

DBMS_OUTPUT is a poor tool to use for logging or debugging: writing to a log table is a much better approach.

As for this one ...

> " Deleting I expect it to increase the paper_cost by 10%."

... your trigger is defined as

```
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON enrols
```

.... so your code never executes.  But once you've fixed that there's a further problem.  If you look at the code you execute for deletions it contains this WHERE clause:

```
WHERE papers.paper_code = :NEW.paper_code;
```

The `:new` value is null because you've deleted the record: you need to use `:old`.